# Does a vampire paladin change lay on hands to deadly touch?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, paladin

> A vampire cleric may become an ex-cleric if his deity does not accept
>   evil clerics, but character can remedy this problem either by changing
>   allegiance or by devoting himself to an evil cause or a source of evil
>   divine power (selecting new domains if appropriate). **A vampire cleric
>   who could normally turn undead loses that ability but gains the
>   ability to rebuke undead, and one who can spontaneously convert spells
>   into cure spells now converts them into inflict spells.**

Does the paladin get treated similarily? Does the positive energy of healing turns into inflicting wounds in his case as well? I am asking because one of my players is a vampire paladin, so he is unable to get healed, or rather *harmed* himself and must depend on the rest of the party.

Source: http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/sp/20030824a

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No.**

Why?  Because the rules don't say they do.

At best, they become a fallen paladin and then can become a [blackguard](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/prestigeClasses/blackguard.htm). But blackguards still heal. But, he can use it to hurt other lippy undead!

Comment: Or rebuild as a [Paladin of sLaughter](http://www.dndsrd.net/unearthedCoreClass.html#freedom-slaughter-and-tyranny)

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

Unless specifically stated otherwise, all class features function as normal for a member of any race who takes a level in the class.